# How can TFS 2010 aggregate changeset associations/links from child work items to a parent work item

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-workitem, changeset

I am using TFS 2010.

Is it possible to aggregate changeset associations/links from child work items to a parent work item, so that (for example) a requirement gets automatically linked/associated to all the changesets linked to its child tasks?

I had an impression and I was expecting that probably TFS Build service will automatically do this job. But now as I trialed with TFS Build, it does not seems to be doing anything for rolling up (and aggregating) changeset associations from child work items to parent work items. I think it is only associating the new/recent changesets to the current build.

Comment: I guess the best approach might be to use the database-structure of the TFS application tier. There you can perform queries against the database itself. Be careful there! You could then encapsulate the logic in one single SP or (better) TFS-extension and perform the task after every build.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**TFS Aggregator**](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/)

### Example Uses

- Update the state of a Bug, PBI (or any parent) to "In Progress" when a child gets moved to "In Progress"
- Update the state of a Bug, PBI (or any parent) to "Done" when all children get moved to "Done" or "Removed"
- Update the "Work Remaining" on a Bug, PBI, etc with the sum of all the Task's "Work Remaining".
- Update the "Work Remaining" on a Sprint with the sum of all the "Work Remaining" of its grandchildren (i.e. tasks of the PBIs and Bugs in the Sprint).
- Sum up totals on a single work item (ie Dev Estimate + Test Estimate = Total Estimate)

Answer (score 0):

The linking of the workitems to the changesets and builds are stored in the relational warehouse database.  You can create a query to retrieve the information.

This MSDN page shows how the builds link to the changesets and then to the work items.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244691.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/02/01/listing-the-work-items-associated-with-changesets-for-a-path.aspx) is an excellent article by B.Hodges, that depicts how you can retrieve the connection between work items & changesets under a given source control path, by using the `ILinking` service.
You could use this example as a basis in order to build a custom tool that gets your job done. To my best knowledge there isn't such tool available, so I think your best bet is to implement what you need with TFS-SDK.
The excellent [tool](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/) proposed by @KMoraz aggregates relations solely within context of WorkItems, so you 'd be missing the changeset-part.